# Find the longest and the shortest strings in array of Strings

Tags: java

I have a problem. When I extract the shortest and the longest strings out of an array, it takes out the very first element that is not needed. How to write an algorithm correctly? Code is below: Thank You!

```
    int max = words[0].length();
    int min = words[0].length();


    StringBuilder sbMax = new StringBuilder();
    StringBuilder sbMin = new StringBuilder();

    for (int q = 1; q < words.length; q++) {
        

        if (words[q].length() >= max) {
            max = words[q].length();

            sbMax.append(words[q]).append(" ");

        }
        else if (words[q].length() <= min) {
            min = words[q].length();

            sbMin.append(words[q]).append(" ");


        }
    }
```

I have a text:

> "When I was younger, so much younger than today I never needed
> anybody's help in any way But now these days are gone, I'm not so
> self-assured Now I find I've changed my mind I've opened up the doors"

The result should be:
2 arrays:

short array: "I", "s", "m"
long array: "younger", "anybody", "assured", "changed"

I've already done RegEx before.
Right now i get at long array a word "When" from the 'int max = words[0].length();'

Comment: Your loop starts on the 2nd element.

Comment: What is the result you would like to have?

Comment: `for (int q = 1; q < words.length; q++)`, arrays start at zero. Change to `for (int q = 0; q < words.length; q++)`

Comment: just updated the question

Comment: int max = 0;
int min = Integer.MAX_VALUE;  and start loops with 0 index

Comment: @JCWasmx86 And then what? Initializing min and max from the 0th element and then looping from index 1 is a sound approach. And to my taste (maybe not to yours).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not clearing the StringBuilder when get new max/min value. And start from index 0 because that string might need in the answer also.

```
StringBuilder sbMax = new StringBuilder();
StringBuilder sbMin = new StringBuilder();

for (int q = 0; q < words.length; q++) {
    // Clear the StringBuilder
    if (words[q].length() > max) {
        sbMax.setLength(0);
    }
    else if (words[q].length() < min) {
        sbMin.setLength(0);
    }

    if (words[q].length() >= max) {
        max = words[q].length();
        sbMax.append(words[q]).append(" ");
    }
    else if (words[q].length() <= min) {
        min = words[q].length();
        sbMin.append(words[q]).append(" ");
    }
}
```

And if better to use ArrayList when store the result rather just adding by space.

Comment: Thank you so much! It worked. I'm not allowed to use ArrayList and other containers, so started using StringBuilder

Answer (score 0):

You can take advantage of streams to find them:

```
int smallest = Arrays.stream(words).mapToInt(s1 -> s1.length()).min().orElse(-1);
int largest = Arrays.stream(words).mapToInt(s1 -> s1.length()).max().orElse(Integer.MAX_VALUE);

String sbMax = Arrays.stream(words).filter(s -> s.length() == largest).collect(Collectors.joining(" "));
String sbMin = Arrays.stream(words).filter(s -> s.length() == smallest).collect(Collectors.joining(" "));
```

This will first find the smallest and largest length word in your array, then it will get all the words that match the smallest and largest and combined them into a single String `sbMax` and `sbMin`

Comment: You could also simply write ```.min(Comparator.comparingInt(String::length)```

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't consider when there are multiple words of the same length.

Comment: when i posted my answer the OP had different text. He updated it since then

Comment: updated my answer to reflect the OPs changes as my original answer was posted before OP modified his question

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way that may be more in line with what you're supposed to do.

I provided just a sample of words but you should try it on your own list. This also ignores duplicate words.

```
StringBuilder maxWords = new StringBuilder();
StringBuilder minWords = new StringBuilder();


String[] words = "I am I so big foo a giant horse a foo horse".split("\\s+");

int max = words[0].length();
int min = max;

for (int q = 1; q < words.length; q++) {
    String currentWord = words[q];
    int currentLength = currentWord.length();
    if (currentLength <= min) {
        if (currentLength < min) {
            min = currentLength;
            minWords.setLength(0);
        }
        if (minWords.indexOf(currentWord) == -1) {
        minWords.append(currentWord + " ");
        }
    } else if (currentLength >= max) {
        if (currentLength > max) {
            max = currentLength;
            maxWords.setLength(0);
        }
        if (maxWords.indexOf(currentWord) == -1) {
            maxWords.append(currentWord + " ");
        }
    }
}

System.out.println("Max: " + maxWords);
System.out.println("Min: " + minWords);
```

Prints

```
Max: giant horse 
Min: I a
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! This way is more effective, and I would use it if i could, but i'm not allowed to use any containers

Comment: I modified my method to use StringBuilder.  The results are the same as before.  I hope this works for you.